# Filter multidimensional array by deep subarray column value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, filtering

I found [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) but I'm still not sure what to use. I have this array:

```
Array (
  [unique_key] => 7439db65fe2856a636e3c6d9841b51ed
  [thwepof_options] => Array (
    [order_date] => Array (
      [name] => order_date
      [value] => 29-01-2018, monday
      [label] => Order date
      [options] => 
    )
  )
)
```

So first I just foreach every `[thwepof_options] => value`, sorted and made them unique (because I need that once):

```
<?php foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $order_dates => $order_date): ?>
    <?php $options = $order_date['thwepof_options']; ?>
        <?php foreach($options as $option => $dates): ?>
            <?php array_push($myarray, $dates['value']) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php sort($myarray); ?>
<?php $unique = array_unique($myarray); ?>
//later in that code
<?php foreach($unique as $dates => $date_value): ?>
            <tr>
                <h1><?php echo $date_value ?></h1></td>
            </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

With `WC()->cart->get_cart()` method I can get the whole array. I need some kind of filter which removes every value from that array where `$date_value` isn't equal with the `[thwepof_options] => [value]` (or show only those where is equal) to make an another `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
array_filter(
        $unique, // Array to filter
        function($elem){ // Closure performing filtration
            // When this returns FALSE, items will be removed
            return $elem['order_date']['value'] == $date_value;
        }
    );
```

It is not entirely clear where you are sourcing all of your values because not all code is provided, but I hope this successfully demonstrates an easy way to filter your array.